# Need help manipulating an array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find the the best time to buy and sell these "stocks". For instance in array "f" buying on 3 and selling at 15 would = maximum_profit. I'm struggling to figure this out, starting to feel slightly dumb. I need to iterate through the array and find the best combo but once I pass a "day" I cant sell it on a day before that, only after.

```
 a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
 b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] 
 c = [3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 4, 9, 8, 5] 
 d = [8, 6, 9, 2, 7, 4, 1, 5 ,1] 
 e = [10, 11, 2, 9, 4, 3, 5, 6] 
 f = [17, 3, 6, 9, 15, 8, 6, 1, 10] 

 def stock_picker(array)
   min = array.min
   min_price= array.index(min)
   max = array.max
   max_price = array.index(max)

 end

 stock_picker(a)
```

Comment: Why is there a rule for the `max` being last in there?

Comment: edited. I used the start of someones elses project for reference.

Comment: I added a benchmark to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a more Ruby way to solve the problem. The key here is to leverage tools like [`combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) to do a lot of the heavy lifting for you, then transform that data step by step into the desired end result:

```
def max_profit(prices)
  best = prices.combination(2).map do |buy, sell|
    [ buy, sell, sell - buy ]
  end.max_by do |buy, sell, profit|
    profit
  end

  if (best[2] <= 0)
    {
      profit: 0
    }
  else
    {
      buy: {
        at: best[0],
        on: prices.index(best[0])
      },
      sell: {
        at: best[1],
        on: prices.index(best[1])
      },
      profit: best[2]
    }
  end
end

stocks = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
  [3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 4, 9, 8, 5],
  [8, 6, 9, 2, 7, 4, 1, 5 ,1],
  [10, 11, 2, 9, 4, 3, 5, 6],
  [17, 3, 6, 9, 15, 8, 6, 1, 10]
] 

stocks.each do |prices|
  p max_profit(prices)
end
```

This gives you results like this:

```
{:buy=>{:at=>1, :on=>0}, :sell=>{:at=>9, :on=>8}, :profit=>8}
{:profit=>0}
{:buy=>{:at=>2, :on=>2}, :sell=>{:at=>9, :on=>6}, :profit=>7}
{:buy=>{:at=>2, :on=>3}, :sell=>{:at=>7, :on=>4}, :profit=>5}
{:buy=>{:at=>2, :on=>2}, :sell=>{:at=>9, :on=>3}, :profit=>7}
{:buy=>{:at=>3, :on=>1}, :sell=>{:at=>15, :on=>4}, :profit=>12}
```

One of the important properties about `combination` is it preserves the order of the elements so this automatically excludes trades that would be impossible by happening in the wrong order.

Comment: Good solution. Any reason not to use `Array#max_by` instead of `#sort_by` and `#last`?

Comment: @moveson You could absolutely do that as well, good observation. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm sure this is a great solution but I'm having trouble understanding it all. I havent seen a block written the way you do them before. How is profit fitting it there? |buy, sell, profit|?

Comment: The first step expands individual pairs of `buy,sell` prices into an array of `buy, sell, profit`. This produces an array of arrays. The next step plucks out the highest profiting one.

Comment: should max_by be on a new line? for readability anyways, it's throwing me off unless there's a reason behind it..

Comment: No, it's chained on with `.` because it's a secondary transformation. In Ruby `a(x).b(y).c(z)` is a common pattern.

Comment: end.max_by do |buy, sell, profit|
    profit.................is this just another way of saying buy, sell = profit? Sorry man, really want to understand this.

Comment: This would be similar to `max_by(function(buy, sell, profit) { return profit; })` in JavaScript if you're more familiar with that. Ruby block notation is a little odd, but until you understand it you're going to be missing one of the most common building blocks in writing Ruby code. If your reference doesn't cover this in enough detail that's something to look for a better book or site that explains.

Comment: Excellent observation that `Array#combination` could be used.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is an exercise to find an efficient way of solving the problem.

**Code**

```
def buy_sell(prices)
  n = prices.size
  imax = (1..n-1).max_by { |i| prices[i] }
  imin = (0..imax-1).min_by { |i| prices[i] }
  return [imin, imax] if imax >= n-2
  imin_next, imax_next = buy_sell(prices[imax+1..-1]).map { |i| i + imax }
  prices[imin]-prices[imax] >= prices[imin_next]-prices[imax_next] ? [imin, imax] :
    [imin, imax]
end
```

This is for `prices.size >= 2`.

**Example**

```
prices = [17, 3, 6, 9, 15, 8, 6, 1, 10]
buy_sell(prices)
  #=> [1, 4]
```

This means that the greatest profit can be made by buying at `prices[1] #=> 3` on day (offset of `prices`) `1` and selling at `prices[4] #=> 15` on day `4`, for a profit of `12`.

**Explanation**

Consider the following array of daily prices.

```
prices = [17, 3, 6, 9, 15]
```

`17` is the price on day (offset) `0`, `3` is the price on day `1`, and so on.

We might first determine the index `i > 0` of `prices` for which `prices[i]` is greatest.

```
n = prices.size
  #=> 5
imax = (1..n-1).max_by { |i| prices[i] }
  #=> 4
```

Since `imax #=> 4` we see that `prices`' largest value after the first day is on its last day, where `prices[imax] #=> 15`. That tells us that regardless of when we will buy, we should sell on the last day (proved easily by contradiction). It therefore remains to compute:

```
imin = (0..imax-1).min_by { |i| prices[i] }
  #=> 1
```

We therefore should buy on day `1`, at `prices[1] #=> 3` and sell on day `4` at `15`, giving us a tidy profit of `12`.

Of course, the largest price after the first day is not necessarily on the last day. Now suppose:

```
 prices = [17, 3, 6, 9, 15, 8, 6, 1, 10]
```

which is the OP's example. The calculation of the maximum price after the first day is now:

```
n = prices.size
  #=> 9
imax = (1..n-1).max_by { |i| prices[i] }
  #=> 4
```

`15`, on day `4` is still the highest price and we already know that before day `4`, day `1` has the lowest price. This allows us to conclude the following: we should either buy on day `1` and sell on day `4`, or we should buy after day `4` (and sell after that). Again, this is easily proved by contradiction, as selling anytime after day `4` will give us a sell price of at most `15`, so we cannot have a larger profit than `12` by buying before day `4`. The remaining problem is the array

```
 prices = [8, 6, 1, 10]
```

where `8` is the price on day `5`, and so on.

Since the largest sell price in this array is at the end, we know that the optimum is to buy at `1` on day `7` (offset `2` of the new `prices`) and sell on day `8` (offset `3`), yielding a profit of `9`. Since `9 < 12` we see that the highest profit is what we calculated initially.

Had `prices` here been `[1, 10, 8, 6]` we would have computed the same profit of `9`, but then had to consider `prices` being the array `[8, 6]`. Had `prices` here been `[8, 1, 10, 6]` we would have computed the same profit of `9`, but then had to consider `prices` being the array `[6]`, which we could disregard since it only contains single price.

This algorithm lends itself to a recursive implementation.

**Efficiency**

If there are `m` subarrays to consider, the time complexity is O(mn), compared to O(n<sup>2</sup>) for a straightforward comparison of all pairs `[prices[i], prices[j]]`, `i < j`.

I have performed a benchmark to compare this approach with a simplified version of that used by @tadman, which enumerates all ordered pairs. The results are as follows.

```
def cary_buy_sell(prices)
  n = prices.size
  imax = (1..n-1).max_by { |i| prices[i] }
  imin = (0..imax-1).min_by { |i| prices[i] }
  return [imin, imax] if imax >= n-2
  imin_next, imax_next = cary_buy_sell(prices[imax+1..-1]).map { |i| i + imax }
  prices[imin]-prices[imax] >= prices[imin_next]-prices[imax_next] ? [imin, imax] :
    [imin, imax]
end

def tadman_buy_sell(prices)
  prices.combination(2).max_by { |x,y| y-x }
end

require 'fruity'

m = 20
[10, 20, 100, 1000].each do |n|
  puts "\nn = #{n}, m = #{m}"
  prices = m.times.map { n.times.to_a.shuffle }
  compare do
    tadman { prices.each { |row| tadman_buy_sell(row) } }
    cary   { prices.each { |row| cary_buy_sell(row) } }
  end
end
```

reports the following.

```
n = 10, m = 20
Running each test 16 times. Test will take about 1 second.
cary is faster than tadman by 1.9x ± 0.1

n = 20, m = 20
Running each test 8 times. Test will take about 1 second.
cary is faster than tadman by 4x ± 0.1

n = 100, m = 20
Running each test once. Test will take about 1 second.
cary is faster than tadman by 22x ± 1.0

n = 1000, m = 20
Running each test once. Test will take about 28 seconds.
cary is faster than tadman by 262x ± 10.0
```

Out of curiosity I computed the average number of recursions required for each value of `n` tested. The results are as follows.

```
           average number of
    n     recursions required
---------------------------
     10          2.40
     20          2.55
    100          4.50
  1,000          6.65
 10,000          8.55
 50,000          9.85
100,000         11.60
500,000         13.40
```

When `n` equals `100`, for example, on average, a sequence of `4.50` recursive calculations were required (i.e., each determining the maximum value of a subarray of prices and then determining the minimum value preceding the maximum). Not unexpectedly, that number increases slowly as `n` is increased.