# Bug in my Ruby counter

Tags: ruby

It is only counting once for each word. I want it to tell me how many times each word appears.

```
dictionary = ["to","do","to","do","to","do"]
string = "just do it to"

 def machine(word,list)
   initialize = Hash.new 

   swerve = word.downcase.split(" ")

     list.each do |i|
       counter = 0 

         swerve.each do |j|
           if i.include? j 
             counter += 1 
         end
       end
       initialize[i]=counter
     end
     return initialize
   end

 machine(string,dictionary)
```

Comment: have you considered trying it with a test string that contains more than one of some words?

Comment: I just did. it counts....but it's counting my string. What in the world is backwards?

Comment: When you give an example you should always show the desired output. I really don't understand what you are trying to do. Firstly, since you names the first array, "dictionary", I would not expect it to contain duplicates.  Also, what should be the format of the returned value ? A hash, perhaps?

Comment: I believe you left me a comment but then deleted it. You made some good points, so I wanted to reply, but have been a little tardy in doing so. It's important to understand that while answers are primarily directed to askers, they are also intended to be of educational value to other members whose Ruby experience varies tremendously. I opt to always provide answers that show how an experienced Rubiest would do it, together with at least a partial explanation of how it works (recognizing that mine is not usually the only answer)...

Comment: ...You mentioned my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261129/need-help-manipulating-an-array-in-ruby/45262565#45262565). I found the question very interesting, posing a challenge to construct an efficient algorithm for computing a solution. I could not avoid using some more advanced techniques, such as recursion, which I could not expect a Ruby newbie to follow, but @tadman had already provide a clear answer to the problem, so I laid out my solution for the benefit of anyone who found it interesting.

Comment: That makes sence, I deleted my comment because I figured you gave an answer not just for me but for the whole community. I had just recognized that you know what you're doing and was hoping to get some answers I'll understand in tbe future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that, for each word in `string`, you wish to determine the number of instances of that word in `dictionary`. If so, the first step is to create a *counting hash*.

```
dict_hash = dictionary.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word,h| h[word] += 1 }
  #=> {"to"=>3, "do"=>3}
```

(I will explain this code later.)

Now split `string` on whitespace and create a hash whose keys are the words in string and whose values are the numbers of times that the value of `word` appears in `dictionary`.

```
string.split.each_with_object({}) { |word,h| h[word] = dict_hash.fetch(word, 0) }
  #=> {"just"=>0, "do"=>3, "it"=>0, "to"=>3}
```

This of course assumes that each word in `string` is unique. If not, depending on the desired behavior, one possibility would be to use another counting hash.

```
string = "to just do it to"
string.split.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word,h|
  h[word] += dict_hash.fetch(word, 0) }
  #=> {"to"=>6, "just"=>0, "do"=>3, "it"=>0}
```

Now let me explain some of the constructs above.

I created two hashes with the form of the class method [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a parameter equal to the desired *default value*, which here is zero. What that means is that if

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

and `h` does not have a key equal to the value `word`, then `h[word]` will return `h`'s default value (and the hash `h` will not be changed). After creating the first hash that way, I wrote `h[word] += 1`. Ruby expands that to

```
h[word] = h[word] + 1
```

before she does any further processing. The first word in `string` that is passed to the block is `"to"` (which is assigned to the block variable `word`). Since the hash `h` is is initially empty (has no keys), `h[word]` on the right side of the above equality returns the default value of zero, giving us

```
h["to"] = h["to"] + 1
  #=>   = 0 + 1 => 1
```

Later, when `word` again equals `"to"` the default value is not used because `h` now has a key `"to"`.

```
h["to"] = h["to"] + 1
  #=>   = 1 + 1 => 2
```

I used the well-worn method [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object). To a newbie this might seem complex. It isn't. The line

```
dict_hash = dictionary.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word,h| h[word] += 1 }
```

is effectively<sup>1</sup> the same as the following.

```
h = Hash.new(0)
dict_hash = dictionary.each { |word| h[word] += 1 }
h
```

In other words, the method allows one to write a single line that creates, constructs and returns the hash, rather than three lines that do the same.

Notice that I used the method [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) for retrieving values from the hash:

```
dict_hash.fetch(word, 0)
```

`fetch`'s second argument (here `0`) is returned if `dict_hash` does not have a key equal to the value of `word`. By contrast, `dict_hash[word]` returns `nil` in that case.

<sup>1 The reason for "effectively" is that when using `each_with_object`, the variable `h`'s scope is confined to the block, which is generally a good programming practice. Don't worry if you haven't learned about "scope" yet.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this using [`Array#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-count) rather easily:

```
def machine(word,list)
  word.downcase.split(' ').collect do |w|
    # for every word in `word`, count how many appearances in `list`
    [w, list.count { |l| l.include?(w) }]
  end.to_h
end

machine("just do it to", ["to","do","to","do","to","do"]) # => {"just"=>0, "do"=>3, "it"=>0, "to"=>3}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for, but it seems like you're approaching this backwards

Convert your string "string" into an array, remove duplicate values and iterate through each element, counting the number of matches in your array "dictionary". The enumerable method [:count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) is useful here.

A good data structure to output here would be a hash, where we store the unique words in our string "string" as keys and the number of occurrences of these words in array "dictionary" as the values. Hashes allow one to store more information about the data in a collection than an array or string, so this fits here.

```
dictionary = [ "to","do","to","do","to","do" ]

string = "just do it to"

def group_by_matches( match_str, list_of_words )

   ## trim leading and trailing whitespace and split string into array of words, remove duplicates.

   to_match = match_str.strip.split.uniq
   groupings = {}

   ## for each element in array of words, count the amount of times it appears *exactly* in the list of words array. 
   ## store that in the groupings hash

   to_match.each do | word |
     groupings[ word ] = list_of_words.count( word )
   end

   groupings
end

group_by_matches( string, dictionary ) #=>  {"just"=>0, "do"=>3, "it"=>0, "to"=>3}
```

On a side note, you should consider using more descriptive variable and method names to help yourself and others follow what's going on.

This also seems like you have it backwards.  Typically, you'd want to use the array to count the number of occurrences in the string. This seems to more closely fit a real-world application where you'd examine a sentence/string of data for matches from a list of predefined words.

Arrays are also useful because they're flexible collections of data, easily iterated through and mutated with enumerable methods. To work with the words in our string, as you can see, it's easiest to immediately convert it to an array of words.

There are many alternatives. If you wanted to shorten the method, you could replace the more verbose each loop with an each_with_object call or a map call which will return a new object rather than the original object like each. In the case of using map.to_h, be careful as to_h will work on a two-dimensional array `[["key1", "val1"], ["key2", "val2"]]` but not on a single dimensional array.

```
## each_with_object

def group_by_matches( match_str, list_of_words )
  to_match = match_str.strip.split.uniq

  to_match.
    each_with_object( {} ) { | word, groupings | groupings[ word ] = list_of_words.count( word ) }
end

## map
def group_by_matches( match_str, list_of_words )
  to_match = match_str.strip.split.uniq

  to_match.
    map { | word | [ word, list_of_words.count( word ) ] }.to_h
end
```

Gauge your method preferences depending on performance, readability, and reliability.

Answer (score 0):

```
list.each do |i|
       counter = 0 

         swerve.each do |j|
           if i.include? j 
             counter += 1
```

needs to be changed to

```
swerve.each do |i|
       counter = 0 

         list.each do |j|
           if i.include? j 
             counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is telling how many times each word in the word/string (the word which is included in the dictionary) appears.
If you want to tell how many times each word in the dictionary appears, you can switch the list.each and swerve.each loops. Then, it will return a hash # => {"just"=>0, "do"=>3, "it"=>0, "to"=>3}

Comment: I had just answered my own question above, I'll mark this correct.

Comment: The purpose of the green checkmark is not to acknowledge that an answer is "correct" (several may correct), but to say, "this answer was the most helpful to me". To do that you need hold off making a quick selection, to allow other members to post answers as well. (Quick selections can also discourage members from posting other answers.) There is no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection; some wait much longer.